# How to transfer files on different computers through clipboard

Tags: clipboard

I have seen a situation many a times where i have to work on VDI desktop/RDP through my laptop where only copy to clipboard option is available.

So if i want to copy a zip file,i cant.

I think one of the option could be convert file to binary and copy to clipboard but how to paste the same on my laptops clipboard and retrieve the the file?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, but most remote desktop software packages offer this feature, and/or a file share feature. Other options are cloud storage such as Dropbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if you are using microsoft's remote desktop, you can copy and paste file between local and remote machine.

It's very difficult to implement the copy and paste between two machine. If you can use the web browser in the remote machine, you can try convert the binary to base64 content, then convert it back to binary using some online base64 converter.

Comment: Its actually vdi and i can copy paste text, i have seen some utilities which converts file to binary or base64 content..but somewhere someone mentioned to avoid loss of file it should be converted to binary instead of base64. So even i convert to base64 how will i get back my zip file from that fluke??

Comment: @user2741355 your file is already binary format. convert to base64 won't loss anything, you can convert base64 back to original content. I suggest using base64 because base64 it considered as plain text which it easier for copy & paste to a text editor. after pasted to the target machine, you can use base64 tool or your own program (if you have knowledge to program) to convert them back to file.

Comment: Yes i know good programming, wrote a quick program and worked!!! I am able to convert base64 text to final files!!!

Comment: @user3741355, great to know that.

Answer (score 7):

If you use Windows you can use following procedure:

1. to get your file prepared for the transfer run:
   certutil.exe -encode file.zip filezip.txt
2. next, open the filezip.txt with Notepad and mark all and copy it to the clipboard
3. Open Notepad on the server with the same file name
   notepad.exe filezip.txt
   and paste the content from the clipboard. Save the file.
4. Last step is to convert the file back to binary using certutil again:
   certutil.exe -decode filezip.txt file.zip
   Now you can extract your files from the file.zip on the server.